# Why are my buttons not working in solidjs?

Tags: javascript, button, solid-js

I'm working on a project in solidjs. For some time now when I click on every button present in my application it does not report. I don't know why because I haven't modified any of my buttons. I'm working on MS Edge, believing it's a browser issue, I re-ran my app on Opera but no success. I also stopped my server then restarted it but nothing. I even shut down my computer and restarted it after a while with no success. So I deleted then reinstalled my node_modules folder but without success. I still face the same problem. I searched the internet for solutions but couldn't find anything about it. I'm working on solid-js version 1.3.3. Thank you for your help !

Comment: So the buttons were working, and some time ago they stopped? Or have they never worked at all?
Are you working with git? Can you trace down the commit that has broken the buttons?
Without seeing a source/repro, the bug can be anywhere.
If you create a new project with `npx degit solidjs/templates/ts my-app`, does everything work fine?
If you try attaching the event-listeners yourself (with `el.addEventListener()`), do they work?

Comment: The buttons worked before and I used them fluently. I don't work with git but on my localhost.

Comment: Could you post some code for us to look at? Specifically your button code.